# Mockito swallows up stack trace?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Why does Mockito swallow up stack traces? For example, if I have a

```
public class Foo
{
    public void foo()
    {
        bar();
    }

    public void bar()
    {
        baz();
    }

    public void baz()
    {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

and a test such as

```
public class MockTest
{
    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        Mockito.spy(new Foo()).foo();
    }
}
```

the exception thrown always looks like

```
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at Foo.baz(Foo.java:17)
    at MockTest.test(MockTest.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

** **So, where is all the stuff between**

```
Foo.baz(Foo.java:17)
MockTest.test(MockTest.java:11)
```

**?**

(The example provided here is a just a simplification -- I'm dealing with a lot more indirections, classes, and so forth. I can't have Mockito swallowing up the critical parts of a partial mock stack trace...)

Comment: perhaps the compiler inlined it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**YES**, mockito cleans stacktraces !

The piece of code at work [`StackTraceFilter`](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/v1.10.10/src/org/mockito/internal/exceptions/stacktrace/StackTraceFilter.java)

There are different ways to disable that

- Since Mockito 1.10.10, provide your own `StackTraceCleanerProvider` via the mockito extension mechanism (create a resource file `mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.StackTraceCleanerProvider` with the qualified name of your implementation)
- Override the `cleansStackTrace` method in a custom `IMockitoConfiguration`, look [there](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.8/org/mockito/configuration/IMockitoConfiguration.html) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

This is the magic of proxies.

The javadoc of [`Mockito.spy()][1]` states

> Creates a spy of the real object. The spy calls real methods unless they are stubbed.

So `spy()` returns a mock object, which is a proxy. It is a sub class of `Foo` so it inherits the methods, but it wraps their execution in a interceptor method. This method has a try catch block which catches any exception thrown in the *actual* method invocation. The catch block then uses a [`ConditionalStackTraceFilter`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/internal/exceptions/base/ConditionalStackTraceFilter.html) to clean up the stack trace. To do this, it uses a [`StackTraceFilter`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/internal/exceptions/base/StackTraceFilter.html) which in the comments of its `filter(..)` method states

```
/**
 * Example how the filter works (+/- means good/bad):
 * [a+, b+, c-, d+, e+, f-, g+] -> [a+, b+, g+]
 * Basically removes all bad from the middle. If any good are in the middle of bad those are also removed. 
 */
```

The call stack at the invocation of `baz()` is something like (super simplified)

```
at Foo.baz()
at FooPROXY.baz()
at Foo.bar()    
at FooPROXY.bar()
at Foo.foo()
at FooPROXY.foo()
at MockTest.test()
```

All the `PROXY` stack trace elements, which are the proxies and the interceptors involved, and everything in between get removed. So you get the result you see.

---

Note that Junit also cleans it up so as not to show its internals.